# Android - exit activity on item click in recycler view

Tags: android, list, android-activity, android-recyclerview, exit

I've got a bunch of list items in my RecyclerView. I am handling the clicks properly for each item, but I need to close the activity when any item is clicked. Becuase RecyclerView doesn't have `setOnItemClickListener` method, I have to do this within the adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Holder holder, int position) {
    // ...

    holder.flagNameTextView.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Go back to the previous activity
            // such as onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}
```

But of course, the adapter is not extending the Activity, so I can't use `onBackPressed()` or `finish()`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling activity from ViewHolder in RecyclerView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688620/calling-activity-from-viewholder-in-recyclerview)

Comment: @Prajnan Bhuyan Yes, but like I said in the question, I can't use the `finish()` method because the click is within the adapter which is NOT extending `Activity` class.

Comment: Pass the context object in the constructor of the Adapter and call context.finish() wherever you want your activity to be finished

[See this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32136973/681929)

Comment: @Prajan You cannot call finish from an Adapter class @ Milan You need to "extract" the click event from the Adapter and set it from the Activity...  and that's been addressed several places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Following:

Declare context globally.

```
Context c;
```

Then type-cast context with your activity.

```
((YourActivity)c).finish();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Coupling the adapter to the activity is a bad idea

Comment: @cricket_007 why is it a bad idea? What would you suggest?

Comment: should getActivity() improve the situation?

Comment: @Milan See the duplicate I flagged

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference of your activity throw the adapter constructor and call Activity.finish();

Hope this Helps.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the context from the `flagNameTextView` :

```
((Activity)holder.flagNameTextView.getContext()).finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides, you can define a interface callback like OnClickListener in RecyclerView adapter. Then Implement this interface in Activity, pass it into the adapter and then use it in View's OnClickListner callback.

Answer (score -1):

Just use YourActivityName.this.finish().

By adding the Activity name you are telling android which "this" you want.

This will only work if your adapter is NOT defined as a static class.